# How can I load this image into an autocomplete text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hopefully you can help me with this small issue, I think it is more about my logic than anything.

I found some good starter code online and I have a nice little text box that searches through a table, this works fine, it should return me a product name and image, my question is:

a) How can I bring in the image?

b) Once an item is selected, how can I get it to redirect to that page?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").autocomplete("Search_VB.ashx", {
            width: 500,
            formatItem: function (data, i, n, value) {
                return "<img style = 'width:50px;height:50px' src='" + value.split("-")[1] + "'/> " + value.split("-")[0];
            },
            formatResult: function (data, value) {
                return value.split("-")[0];
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The page it posts to looks like this (Search_VB.ashx):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Text

Public Class Search_VB : Implements IHttpHandler
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim prefixText As String = context.Request.QueryString("q")
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandText = ("select imgstr, name, sku, id, url from searchtbl where name like '%' + @SearchText + '%'")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText)
    cmd.Connection = conn
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
    conn.Open()
    Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While sdr.Read
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0} {1}-{2}", sdr("imgstr"), sdr("name"), sdr("sku"), Environment.NewLine))
    End While
    conn.Close()
    context.Response.Write(sb.ToString)
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property
End Class
```

I suspect it may have something to do with the split (sorry, I am a newbie), it kind of works but the image doesn't show. Also, once the item is selected, how can I just get the page to fire straight off to the url that is returned?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This link might give you what you want to achieve [JQuery Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) and instead of returning string data, return `JSON` data from your `.ashx` code something like this:

```
var projects = [
{
value: "jquery",
label: "jQuery",
desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
icon: "image1.jpg"
},
{
value: "jquery-ui",
label: "jQuery UI",
desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
icon: "image2.jpg"
},
{
value: "sizzlejs",
label: "Sizzle JS",
desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
icon: "image3.jpg"
}
];
```

Note: I have taken this `JSON` from the given autocomplete link example itself.

use this `JSON` data as source for autocomplete and moreover autocomplete has Extension Point [_renderItem](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) which let's you format the autocomplete items, here is an example

```
$("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").autocomplete(...<YOUR_CODE_TO_GET_JSON_DATA>...).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
return $("<li>")
.append("<a href='URL'><div><span><img src="+item.icon+"/></span>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</div></a>")
.appendTo(ul);
};
```

Hope this helps...Happy coding..